# "Continuity" of Expectation for Almost constant Seq of R.V's

Tags: probability-theory

The next question is given from "A First Course In Probability", Chapter 8 , theoretical questions number 4.

We are given $(Z_n)_n$ seq of Random variables, and a constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$ , such that $ \forall \epsilon >0, P( |{Z_n-C}| > \epsilon ) $ converges to $0$ ( i.e converges in probability to C). Then, any continous bounded function g holds 
$ \mathbb{E}[g(Z_n)] \mapsto g(C) $ when $n$ goes to $\infty$.

I'm pretty stuck with my attempts to prove that claim, and appreciate solution for that.

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: How we prood that claim ? :)